# Proprietary driver for my laptop k40ab (ATI HD4570)

Tags: ati, configuration, proprietary

I have always used the built-in utility to install the driver for my video card (HD4570). Now running Ubuntu 11.04 as a live-cd and updating the repository - the utility does not show the available proprietary drivers.

Maybe I just need to install Ubuntu, or download driver from the video card manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial idea is correct, you need to install Ubuntu first, and then you can either wait for the Additional Drivers to prompt you or just [ask it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-proprietary-drivers) to install it for you.